# Decrypt Google Pay payment token using Go

Tags: go, google-pay, tink

I want to implement the decryption of Google Pay payment tokens using the Go language. Google strongly recommends using the Tink library.

I have looked at the instructions provided [here](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/docs/GOLANG-HOWTO.md), but couldn't figure out how to convert an already existing private and public key pair to a keyset. If it isn't possible, should I generate a private and public keyset using Tink first and then send it to Google?

If anyone can provide a working example of the Google Pay payment token using Tink library in Go language or a step-by-step guide (even a short one), that would really help. Thank you in advance.